# Parse Framework: Did something go wrong during PFFacebook login? I.e. did the user cancel?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, ios-frameworks

I am using **parse framework's PFFacebook for Facebook login**  in my new project.
When i click on Facebook login button it goes to **PFFacebook login dialog** 
In this dialog I inserted my credentials but didn't pressed **OK** button instead of that I pressed home button by-mistake . And now for reaching into my app I pressed myAppIcon button but now my app hangs.

[image]

**In normal Facebook sdk, they handle login by following method, I want to check the same but with parse framework**

```
// Did something go wrong during login? I.e. did the user cancel?
    if (status == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed || status == FBSessionStateCreatedOpening) {

        // If so, just send them round the loop again
        [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
        FB_CreateNewSession();
    }
    else 
    {
        // Update our game now we've logged in
        if (m_kGameState == kGAMESTATE_FRONTSCREEN_LOGGEDOUT) {
            UpdateView(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need same functionality When user click on cancel button ?

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes i need something like cancel button action when user press home from Facebook login dialog

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want, check the NSLogs to see what happens in each case:

```
    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            }
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        }
    }];
```